# How to set samply rate for MPU sensors?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, sensors

I wanna make a LSTM neural network and now I need collecting data from MPU9250 (with esp32s). But I can not find anything how to set samply rate. So I have 8 mpu and 8 esp, I want get data with 20Hz samply rate. Can you explain how can I do? And if you wanna say some critical  points about collect data you can tell me because it is my first project.

Answer (score 0):

YOU set the sampling rate.  If you want samples at 20Hz, then you read the registers 20 times a second.  You can use `time.sleep` to put your code to sleep for a short period.

Comment: I think it is not good solution. It doesn't seems sensible. Maybe can some values be lost? So how much delay should I put

Comment: How can a value ever be lost?  Those sensors don't compute a value and then throw it away.  When you ask, they return their current readings.  If you want 20 times a second, then you sleep for 0.05 seconds.

Comment: Okey I got it now. Tomorrow I will try. Thank you